# Inform picasso that image changed

Tags: android, picasso

I load an image using Picasso,

```
Picasso.with(this).invalidate(url);
Picasso.with(this)
      .load(url)
      .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE,MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
      .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
      .resize(512,512)
      .noFade()
      .into(editprofileImage);
```

but whenever I change the image, and refresh my ImageView, Picasso still has the bitmap cached.

Is it possible to invalidate the cache in Picasso?